# how to fetch array of objects in class model using swift

Tags: swift, swifty-json

the sample json data is

```
     [
       {
        "id": "244",
        "name": "PIZZAS",
        "subcategory": [
          {
            "id": "515",
            "name": "MARGARITA",
            "description": "Cheese and Tomato",
            "image": "",
            "icon": "",
            "coupon": "1",
            "order": "1",
            "aname": "",
            "options": "2",
            "item": [
                        {
                           "id": "1749",
                           "name": "9 Inch Thin & Crispy Margarita",
                           "description": "",
                           "price": "3.40",
                           "coupon": "1",
                           "image": "",
                           "options": "2",
                           "order": "1",
                           "addon": "495",
                           "aname": "",
                           "icon": ""
                    }]
             }]
        }]
```

my Json data is not the exact. There is number of subcategories and items. I only post here the sample data.

I can able to fetch the main items into the class model . But how to fetch the Subcategory data as well as item data. Because its an array of object.
I have created the class model like this

**Subcategory class**

```
     import Foundation
     class SubCategory {
                       var id: Int?
                       var name: String?
                       var desc: String?
                       var image: String?
                       var coupon: Int?
                       var icon: String?
                       var order: Int?
                       var aname: String?
                       var options: Int?
                       var items:Array<AnyObject>?

init(id:Int?,name:String?,desc:String?,image:String?,coupon:Int?,icon:String?,order:Int?,aname:String?,options:Int?,items:Array<AnyObject>?){
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.desc = name
    self.image = image
    self.coupon = coupon
    self.icon = icon
    self.order = order
    self.aname = aname
    self.options = options
    self.items = items

   }
  }
```

After that I am sending the subcategory data to the class model. but the main item data is going. I know here I am doing mistakes. but how can i enter into the subcategory section

```
          //subcategory section
                   var subcategories = [SubCategory]()
                    for(_,content) in json{ ////here instead of json what should be written so that i can get the subcategory value
                        let subcategory = SubCategory(id: Int(content["id"].stringValue),

                          name: content["name"].string,
                          desc: content["desc"].string,
                          image: content["image"].string,
                          coupon: Int(content["coupon"].stringValue),
                          icon: content["icon"].string,
                          order: Int(content["order"].stringValue),
                          aname: content["aname"].string,
                          options: Int(content["options"].stringValue),
                          items:content["items"].arrayObject)
               subcategories.append(subcategory)

                   }
                   for subcategory in subcategories {
                       print(subcategory.name)
                        print(subcategory.desc)
                        print(subcategory.id)

                    }
                    print(subcategories.count)
```

I want all the subcategories data as well as items data into my modal class. hows the implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want the "subcategory" object from the first element of that JSON array, no?

```
for (_, item) in json {
    //do something with item.id, item.name

    for (_, subcategory) in item["subcategory"] {

        let subcategory = SubCategory(
            id: Int(subcategory ["id"].stringValue),
            name: subcategory ["name"].string,
            desc: subcategory ["desc"].string,
            image: subcategory ["image"].string,
            coupon: Int(subcategory ["coupon"].stringValue),
            icon: subcategory ["icon"].string,
            order: Int(subcategory ["order"].stringValue),
            aname: subcategory ["aname"].string,
            options: Int(subcategory ["options"].stringValue),
            items: subcategory ["items"].arrayObject
        )

        subcategories.append(subcategory)
    }

    //...
}
```

`.append` is gross. In this instance, there's a much nicer way:

```
for (_, item) in json {
    //do something with item.id, item.name

    subcategories = item.1["subcategory"].map{ subcategory in
         return SubCategory(
            id: Int(subcategory ["id"].stringValue),
            name: subcategory ["name"].string,
            desc: subcategory ["desc"].string,
            image: subcategory ["image"].string,
            coupon: Int(subcategory ["coupon"].stringValue),
            icon: subcategory ["icon"].string,
            order: Int(subcategory ["order"].stringValue),
            aname: subcategory ["aname"].string,
            options: Int(subcategory ["options"].stringValue),
            items: subcategory ["items"].arrayObject
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: but if i have so many subcategories then how can i get all subcategories data according to the number of counts

Comment: here only i have sent the sample data of json . my data is not exactly only one subcategory and one  items.

Comment: i have tried your code .  In this line item["subcategory"]  the error is "(string,JSON)  has no subscript members

Comment: What happens with `item.1["subcategory"]`?

Comment: I really have no idea. Here I am using swiftyJson

Comment: Its not showing error  but while building so much time  more than expected

Comment: still the compilation is in processing. You can think how much time is it taking that  i am still building the app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115854/discussion-between-amomchilov-and-pradip-kumar).